# Java WatchService max of 512 registered directories

Tags: java, watchservice

I'm using the Java WatchService on a Windows box to monitor a network drive, it appears to max out at 512 directories after which even though it registers the folders it doesn't appear to be getting any events from them? It does get events from directories 0-511 though? Is this a limitation in the API? Is there any way around it?

Comment: I think a limitation in the underlying OS

Comment: How IDEs like IntelliJ get around it is by periodically (every second) checking for changes in a limited set of files. A file indexer program I know (from before Windows had it built-in) checked the free space and scanned the entire drive when it changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot folks for getting back to me on that. Really wish I'd come across that limitation before relying so heavily on the API.